# I am having trouble plotting a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am currently having trouble plotting a histogram. There is something wrong with my coding but I am not sure how to fix it. Can someone explain what I need to change or add?

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = traumaclinical, aes(iss, baseline_wcc)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 15) +
  labs(x = "Injury Severity", y = "WCC", 
       title = "Comparing WCC groups against Injury Severity Score", 
       colour = "WCC Group") +
  scale_colour_manual(values =c("pink","lightblue","purple"))
```

[image: In this diagram you can see the error that keeps popping up]

Comment: Histograms use data from one column and you are supplying data from two: `iss` and `baseline_wcc`. Which of those do you want to use? It would help to see some data from `traumaclinical` in a plain text format and have some idea of desired output.

Comment: Do you need `geom_col() +` instead of `geom_histogram(binwidth = 15) +`?